# How to parse/ iterate and fetch a multi nested json array in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, multidimensional-array, backend

I have this response from a restapi and wnat to access the replies inside of comments i do have the model from [quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io) but don't know how to iterate and fetch the data.

```
  "data": {
"_id": "61ee65fd92a48c7b10779f24",
"topicName": "Test Topic",
"description": "<p>Test Discussion</p>",
"createdByName": "Admin",
"comments": [
  {
    "_id": "622740a70fdfbb1bdd00232b",
    "comment": "post commnet test",
    "commentedById": "611cb5ecaf1a1bbc858d4d13",
    "user": [
      {
        "title": "Mr",
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Cart",
        "userID": "USER1000022",
        "_id": "611cb5ecaf1a1bbc858d4d13"
      }
    ],
    "replies": []
  },
  {
    "_id": "620d05382773643acd49177b",
    "comment": "test message",
    "commentedById": "611cb5ecaf1a1bbc858d4d13",
    "commentedByName": "Mr. John Cart",
    "user": [
      {
        "title": "Mr",
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Cart",
        "userID": "USER1000022",
        "_id": "611cb5ecaf1a1bbc858d4d13"
      }
    ],
    "replies": [
      {
        "_id": "6227351b0fdfbb099800232a",
        "comment": "test msg",
        "commentedById": "611cb5ecaf1a1bbc858d4d13",
        "commentedByName": "Mr, john cart",
        "replyUser": [
          {
            "title": "Mr",
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "cart",
            "userID": "USER1000022",
            "_id": "611cb5ecaf1a1bbc858d4d13"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
  },
```

any help or documentations/ suggestions / guides would be helpfull

**Thank you**

Comment: [Here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/serializing-your-object-in-flutter-ab510f0b8b47) is an article on serializing/deserializing objects in Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

```
var object= json.decode(response.body)
```

object variable must be in repeated syntax

```
 print(object["data"]["comments"][index]["replies"]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Fetch data from the internet**

This recipe uses the following steps:

1. Add the http package.
2. Make a network request using the http package.
3. Convert the response into a custom Dart object.
4. Fetch and display the data with Flutter.

`dependencies: http: <latest_version>`

import the http package

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

Additionally, in your AndroidManifest.xml file, add the Internet permission.

```
<!-- Required to fetch data from the internet. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**Make a network request**

```
Future<YourModel> fetchData() async {
  final response = await http
      .get(Uri.parse('yourapiurl'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    return YourModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load data');
  }
}
```

**Fetch the data**

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late Future<YourModel> yourAlbum;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    yourModel = fetchData();
  }
  // ···
}
```

**Display the data**

```
FutureBuilder<YourModel>(
  future: futureModel,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return Text(snapshot.data!.title);
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text('${snapshot.error}');
    }

    // By default, show a loading spinner.
    return const CircularProgressIndicator();
  },
)
```